# Is HTTPS enough to secure a PayPal request?

Tags: rest, security, http, paypal, https

I've seem some time ago that PayPal has a RESTful API whose docs are available [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api). It allows for many things to be done directly using just HTTP, among those things we can, for example, create a payment. There's a sample for that [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#create-a-payment).

Using the API seems quite easy, but we can see that for some tasks, like creating a payment, sensitive data has to be sent in the request. In the example I've linked all credit card data is sent to create a credit card payment.

My question is: since we may need to share sensitive data on those API calls, is using HTTPS enough to secure those requests? Is there any other kind of protection we have to add to secure the sensitive data being transfered?

Comment: If PayPal requires any additional security it'll be in the documentation - I doubt they'd roll their own encryption though. HTTPS is secure as long as your trusted root CAs retain their integrity. For paranoid security you can always use cert pinning, assuming they guarantee not to have their certificate fingerprint or whatnot change.

Comment: Paypal requires **TLS1.2** [among other upcoming requirements/changes](https://devblog.paypal.com/upcoming-security-changes-notice/). The "safer" way would be [`Paypal Payment`](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/web/accept-paypal-payment/) (aka "Express Checkout") because no financial info goes over the wire between you (merchant) and Paypal (end users interact directly with Paypal for payment flows). Hth..

Answer (score 0):

you ca use the paypal pro API instead of core restfully of paypal. in paypal pro provides the request encryption provided by the paypal. you can use [see the examples](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-process-credit-cards-with-paypal-payments-pro-using-php--net-25397)

Comment: I don't see any extra encryption in the code at that link. It seems to be standard HTTPS.

Comment: there is a Paypal classes where you can use the request encryption. you can use also this class.
you can also use the SOAP API to make payment, its more preferable to use restfull, read here https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/apiCredentials/

and you can also encrypt request. read https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/encryptedwebpayments/

Comment: The first link seems to be about authentication and not encryption, and the second one seems specific to the embeddable payment buttons instead of the REST API.